# deleting a bar in Build's information

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

first off I'm a total noob if it comes to Jenkins. Let's say I have a project. Now, when I build I have for example 'Build #21', when I then go to 'Edit Build Information' which is on the left-hand site of Jenkins, I then have two bars: One is called 'Display name' and the other one is 'Description'. What should I do to delete the 'Description' bar? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to delete it? you can delete the description inside and from the status section you won't even see it. what's the end game?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understand or if I haven't explained myself fully. I don't want to delete the description one enters (types in) but the whole 'Description' bar/box in which you put the text. I just don't want it there. Oh and it's just for the practice reasons